# Uppercase letter for first array item but still have lowercase letter

Tags: jquery, arrays, uppercase

Sorry guys, i'm a designer trying to do stuff with jQuery when i should be sticking to fonts and colors.

So i'm capitizing the first letter of an array of words. I've got the Capital letter but also the lower case letter still follows it. What's the best way to remove this lower case letter?

My code:

```
$("#generatebutt").click(function() {

 var dumpStr = "";
 var numberOfWords = $('#length').val();
 var numberpara = $('#numberpara').val();

for (var i = 0; i < numberpara; i++) {
ShuffleWords(melbArray);

for (var j = 0; j < numberOfWords; j++) {
    var theWords = melbArray[j];                 
    if(j == 0){
        dumpStr += theWords.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    }
    else {
    }
    if(j % 5 == 1){
        dumpStr += theWords + ", ";
    }
    else {
        dumpStr += theWords + " ";
    }
}
dumpStr = dumpStr.trim();
dumpStr += ".<br/><br/>";
}
$("#dump").html(dumpStr);
});
```

​

Thanking you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the substring method for this, in your first if statement when you add the single uppercase letter to dumpStr you need to remove this first character from the existing string.

```
if(j == 0){
    dumpStr += theWords.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    theWords = theWords.substring(1)
}
```

This will simply remove that first character so when the rest of the string is added to dumpStr later that first lowercase letter will no longer be contained within the string.

Answer (score 2):

instead of looping and converting, you can do something like

```
camelWord = theWords.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()
                     + theWords.substring(1,theWords.length);
```